# Проблема некорректной работы функций дат в SQLite (v3)

Tags: sqlite, null

[image: Хранение дат в виде NUMERIC]
[image: TypeOf теперь TEXT]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные в таблице пустых значений не имеют.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SQLite3 упорно возвращает *NULL* в выборке из таблицы, где даты (FullDate) хранятся в виде *NUMERIC*:

```
SELECT date(FullDate, '%dd') AS FD, FullDate FROM FmtDays;
```

Ни один из шаблонов ('%d', '%YYYY', etc) не срабатывает.
CAST (...) AS TEXT и использование strftime вообще возвращает ТОЛЬКО год.
В чем может быть проблема?

UPD: добавил скрины для наглядности.

Comment: *даты (FullDate) хранятся в виде NUMERIC* Покажите пример таких данных (2-3 значения) и соответствующие им даты.

Comment: Добавил скрин из DB Browser

Comment: FmtDays - это View, обращающийся к таблице Debts, все скрины разместил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно, чего вы собственно хотите добиться. Функция
`DATE` принимает строчную дату и список
модификаторов. Например:

```sql
SELECT DATE('2020-01-01T00:00:00Z', '+3 days')
-- Output: 
--   2020-01-04
```

Если вам нужно вывести день из *Unix*-даты,
то это будет как-то так:

```sql
SELECT STRFTIME('%d', 1598864356, 'unixepoch')
-- Output:
--   31
```

[Документация](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

---

После правки видно, что у вас там `TEXT`,
а не `NUMERIC`. В вашем случае должно
сработать что-то типа такого:

```sql
SELECT STRFTIME('%d', REPLACE(FullDate, '.', '-'));
```

Comment: Ка вы думаете, чего можно хотеть добиться, указывая шаблон '%d'? По вашему примеру сделал точь-в-точь, лишь заменил числовое значение на имя поля. Снова NULL в результате.  SELECT STRFTIME('%d', FullDate, 'unixepoch') FROM FmtDays;

Comment: Значит у вас в `FullDate` лежит либо `NULL`, либо не *Unix*-дата.  Последуйте совету коллеги Akina и добавьте в вопрос образец данных.

Comment: Добавил скрины. NULL'ей в БД нет, просто гарантированно. База юзабельна давно, данные проверяются.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте скринами данные, которые можно передать текстом.  По скриншотами видно, что данные ничуть не `NUMERIC`.  Добавил правку в ответ.

Comment: BalanceDate объявлен как NUMERIC, кастов не было, всего лишь выборка с помощью View. Вопрос тоже, как так может быть, чтобы TypeOf выдал text.

Comment: Спасибо, SELECT STRFTIME('%d', REPLACE(FullDate, '.', '-')); сработало))

Comment: Пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его как верный, нажав галочку рядом с ответом.